# Unable to show json responce in jscript

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I am developing mobile application using Javascript, HTML and CSS. I have to use web services in that app. I am doing a sample demo to see how consume the web service in javascript. I have an url which return JSON response. I need to display this response using jQuery.

This is the url which return tje JSON response

http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo

and the response is:

```
{
    "status": {
        "message":"the daily limit of 30000 credits for demo has been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use the demo account for your application.",
        "value":18
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to display this using javascript. I try with below code but it doest not work

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#btnConvert").click(function()
        {

            $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url:"http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data) 
            {
                $('#currency_converter_result').html(data);
                alert(""+data);

            }
            });
        });
    });
```

It shows an alert box with `[object object]`. 
Could you help me about how to show json response using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can display the message of your object like this:

```
alert(data.status.message);
```

Comment: glad it worked, try using tools like Firebug in Firefox, they make it a lot easier to see the content inside an object and how it is structured for example (console logging etc.) ;)

Answer (score 1):

The object `data` contains the next attributes:

```
- data
    -- status
        -- message: "the daily limit of 30000 credits for demo has been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use the demo account for your application."
        -- value: 18
```

So in order to extract those values you have to use:

```
data.status.message // Returns the String
data.status.value // Returns the code number
```